# Flexslider startat class instead of slide number

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

In Flexslider you have the option to start the slider at a specific slide for example:

```
$(".slider").flexslider({
      startAt: 7
});
```

My problem is that I don't want to start the slider at a specific number. Instead I want to start it at a specific class, for example if my list looked something like:

```
<ul>
...
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li class="active">...</li>
<li>...</li>
...
</ul>
```

Then I would want the first slide to be the one with the class of `.active`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (using jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)):

```
$(".slider").flexslider({
      startAt: $('.slider li.active').index('.slider li');
});
```

[jsFiddle example of .index()](http://jsfiddle.net/JfmvE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

make a simple workaround:

```
$(".slider").flexslider({
      startAt: $('#your_ul_id > li').index($('#your_ul_id > li.active'))
});
```

:P

Comment: Both yours and Yotams example work in principle but not in reality. It should work but FlexSlider just won't get it. Thanks anyway.